# Cant use OrderBy with int[,] - c#

Tags: linq, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to order a 2d array and have been struggling, so I was wondering if anyone can offer me some advice.

I have an array of data that i wish to order all rows depending on the values in first column. i.e.

```
x[0] = {360,0,0,1}      x[0] = {0  ,0,1,0}
x[1] = {180,0,0,0}  to  x[1] = {180,0,0,0}
x[2] = {0  ,0,1,0}      x[2] = {360,0,0,1}
```

When using .OrderBy(x => x[0]) the error:

> 'int[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy and no extension method 'OrderBy'

I am including Systems.Linq but still get the error.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
..
using System.Linq;

public bool signalConditioning(int[,] DCValues)
{
    var DcValuesNormalizeda = DCValues.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What would you expect `x[0]` to be? What would you expect `x` to be? (I'd expect it to be an `int`...)

Comment: Does `int[,]` implement `IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: I realized that I was using the wrong approach i converted the array to a list and did the ordering, then converted to an Array. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
        int[,] x = new int[,]
             {  {360,0,0,1},
             {180,0,0,0},
             {0  ,0,1,0}};

        var list = new List<int[]>();
        for(int i = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var row = new int[x.GetLength(1)];
            for(int j= 0; j < x.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                row[j] = x[i, j];
            }
            list.Add(row);
        }
        var orderedList = list.OrderBy(r => r[0]).ToList();
```

Of course, if you need an array as result, you have to reconstruct it from the `orderedList`.

Note: if performance is important, you could replace the inner loop with a `Buffer.BlockCopy(...)`:

```
        var list = new List<int[]>();
        for(int i = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var row = new int[x.GetLength(1)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(x, i *4* x.GetLength(1),row,0, x.GetLength(1)*4);
            list.Add(row);
        }
        var orderedList = list.OrderBy(r => r[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, I ended up using converting my class array into a list using a similar approach to this. Then Remove duplicates and order the list then converted back to an array. 

Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with LINQ, you can do it like this, but the result is a `List<int[]>`. If you need the result as a two dimensional array, you must use loops and then not using LINQ at all is going to be better.

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(0)).Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(1)).Select(c => x[r,c]).ToArray()).OrderBy(row => row[0]).ToList();
```